# Is there a way to set the clipboard text in Lua?

Tags: windows, lua, clipboard

I'm trying to append a variable to the clipboard.  Is there a way to do this in Lua?

Comment: `os.execute("echo your text|clip.exe")` or create process using `io.popen("clip.exe","w")` and feed your text as stdin to this process

Comment: `clip.exe` exists in Win7 by default, special version exists for WinXP

Answer (score 0):

You can use [set_clipboard](http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html#set_clipboard) method from [winapi](https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi) module.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to do this directly in Vanilla Lua, however you should be able to do so with different modules.

As suggested by Paul Kulchenko, the [winapi](https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi) module is probably a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of @Egor Skriptunoff's comment:

```
function to_clipboard(text)
    local p = io.popen("clip.exe", "w")
    p:write(text)
    p:close()
end
```

Works for me on Win 10 and Lua 5.4.